# 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: Reset password token is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am currently doing a project that using devise gem.. The sign up,confirmation email and also the login is working well. But in forgot password, I am encountering this error.. I tried to check the token in http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/reset_password_instructions by hovering the "change my password" text the token that received is the same in my table

Note: I followed the instruction that i have search regarding to the reset_password file

**Reset Password Instruction**

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

**User Mailer preview**

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

    def confirmation_instructions
        @user = User.last
        @getUser = User.find(@user)
        @token = @getUser.confirmation_token
        Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(@user, @token)
    end

    def reset_password_instructions
        @user = User.last
        @getUser = User.find(@user)
        @token = @getUser.reset_password_token
        Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(@user,@token)
      end
end
```

Question: How can I fix this kind of error?

Comment: Umm..is the user `confirmed` before `resetting` password?

Comment: Yess.. I confirmed it before resetting the password

Comment: Please share the exact error you see..

Comment: Try to change `@token` by `@resource.reset_password_token` in your mailer's view.

Comment: I done with this question.. I'll post my answer

Answer (score 0):

In file of user_mailer_preview and to the method of reset_password_instructions try to add this

```
def reset_password_instructions 
        query = "SELECT * FROM users 
            WHERE reset_password_token IS NOT NULL 
            ORDER by reset_password_sent_at DESC"
        user = User.find_by_sql(query).first
        token = user.send(:set_reset_password_token)
        Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(user, token)

    end
```